# Why answered questions reappear on the main page

Tags: discussion

I always wondered why are the answered questions reappear over the main page. I do know that we can filter question with given options, but this question was always on my mind. Example;

- [How do I enable fancy apt colours and progress bars?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445245/179042)

I'm pretty sure there are valid reasons but all I could think of is reviewing the answered questions, newly added answers are acceptable, updating new information... etc.

Well, maybe I'm too stupid to ask this knowing the answer. But however, I'm just trying to understand how exactly this benefits all the users and are they more meaningful answers.

On a related note, I couldn't find anything similar in here. Hence, the question. If there are any, please assist me finding it.

Comment: Edited posts also go to the main page, is this what you are missing? Also in your example, there is a new answer, this will of pushed it to the top, without this people would never see the answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/818661/75060

Comment: @MarkKirby, I get that and thanks for the reply. However, the same will be on the moderation queue under **review**. Isn't it?

Comment: Only in the case of a late answer, not sure how old the question has to be for that, years I think, or a first post by a new user. Answers are not reviewed just because they are new. Note that the "main page" is actually the "activity page" displaying the most recent activity on posts, this includes edits, answers etc....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "main" page, is actually the "recently active" page. Any activity, like new questions or edits or answers on a post go here.

A real good benefit this has, is that when people edit there posts because they are bad or because they are not getting attention, they become visible to everyone again, so no question (within reason) is ever completely dead and if you improve it, then it can receive views all over again or be reopened if it was bad.

Another situation is when you late answer a question or even just answer in general after a post falls of the "newest questions" list, people will see your answer and they can comment and vote on it.

This page IMO is really for the regulars. We can use it to get a really good idea of what is going on, on an otherwise large and complicated site.

It is also consistent across all SE sites, not just here.